# On button click "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsviewcontroller

Cocoa/Objective-C newbie here.

I have a MainMenu.xib file which has a `NSView`.
This is what `awakeFromNib` in AppDelegate.h looks like :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
NSViewController *x = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
NSView *v = [x view];
[_theView addSubview:v];
```

}

The new view has a button but when I click on it, I get the message "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

I'm completely lost. Please help me with this. Thanks!

It also throws as "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = ...) at the line (in main.m):

```
return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
```

The error is :

2014-10-14 09:05:09.743 FAST Tax Scanner[18408:303] -[OS_dispatch_queue_runloop login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000f7900
2014-10-14 09:05:09.743 FAST Tax Scanner[18408:303] -[OS_dispatch_queue_runloop login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000f7900
2014-10-14 09:05:09.744 FAST Tax Scanner[18408:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9484725c **exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8c72fe75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9484a12d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff947a5272 ___forwarding_** + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff947a4df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b87d260 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b87d0de -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8c9c4d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 128
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8e3655 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2316
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8e2a27 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 487
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8e213d -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 706
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b863a58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11296
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8025d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b6529f9 -[NSApplication run] + 646
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b63d783 NSApplicationMain + 940
    15  FAST Tax Scanner                    0x0000000100001452 main + 34
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff982c55fd start + 1
    17  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)

Comment: Paste in the complete error message so we can see which selector and which instance it's complaining about.  Also, if the error happens on a button click you might want to show the code that executes in response to that button action.

Comment: this can also happen if you wire up things wrong in xcode

Comment: It says that you're calling a `login:` method on an object that doesn't recognize that method.  Since it's not the type of object you would normally be using, I suspect you're trying to use something that has been released.  What does the code look like where you're using a `login:` call?  (Or perhaps you've connected your control to a `login:` method of something that doesn't exist at the time it runs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see....

Try saving `NSViewController *x` as a strong property of the object that creates it instead of having it as a local variable.  The way it's currently created, the `Login` object will not survive past the end of the `awakeFromNib` method.